# Duplicate QUORA question detection:Kaggle Dataset

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, lstm, rnn

I have tried to use 2 BILSTMs along with the attention layer but the validation accuracy is not improving at all. Could anyone suggest an alternative to increase the accuracy?

#### Layer structuring:

```
>Preprocessing
>GLOVE
>BILSTM
>ATTENTION
>BILSTM
```

Current Validation Accuracy for 10 epochs is in the range of 0.62 to 0.63

#### Code:

```
## Embeddings matrix is the set of vectors representing our words 
from keras.initializers import Constant

# Length of the maximum sentence in the df
sequence_length = 470
DROPOUT=0.1


question1 = Input(shape=(max_len,))
question2 = Input(shape=(max_len,))
q1 = Embedding(len(word_index)+1, 
                 embedding_dim, 
                 embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix), 
                 input_length=max_len, 
                 trainable=False)(question1)
q1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True), merge_mode="sum")(q1)
q2 = Embedding(len(word_index)+1, 
                 embedding_dim, 
                 embeddings_initializer=Constant(embedding_matrix), 
                 input_length=max_len, 
                 trainable=False)(question2)
q2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True), merge_mode="sum")(q2)
## Applying Attention
model = dot([q1,q2], [1,1])
model = Flatten()(model)
model = Dense((max_len*300))(model)
model = Reshape((max_len, 300))(model)
model = add([q1,model])
##Applying BiLSTM
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(300, return_sequences=True), merge_mode="sum")(model)
model = Flatten()(model)
model = Dense(200, activation='relu')(model)
model = Dropout(DROPOUT)(model)
model = BatchNormalization()(model)
model = Dense(200, activation='relu')(model)
model = Dropout(DROPOUT)(model)
model = BatchNormalization()(model)
model = Dense(200, activation='relu')(model)
model = Dropout(DROPOUT)(model)
model = BatchNormalization()(model)
model = Dense(200, activation='relu')(model)
model = Dropout(DROPOUT)(model)
model = BatchNormalization()(model)

is_duplicate = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(model)

final_model = Model(inputs=[question1,question2], outputs=is_duplicate)
final_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = final_model.fit([x1_train, x2_train],
                    X_train.is_duplicate.values,
                    epochs=10,
                    verbose=2,
                    validation_data=([x1_test, x2_test], X_test.is_duplicate.values),
                    batch_size=64,
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Is this a case of overfitting according to you? What is the current validation accuracy you have achieved?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal val_acc is in the range of 0.62 to 0.63 for all 10 epochs and acc is in the range of 0.67 to 0.65 which is decreasing and val_acc increased from 0.62-0.63